# How to Subtract a different amount from User if certain role is present Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Discord.JS bot issue; Hello! I'm looking to subtract a lower amount of points from a user if they have a certain role, the Issue I'm having is that the bot subtracts the regular amount of points and then the role-specific amount, where I just want it to subtract one value or the other.

Here's the code before I tried creating the different values, any help would be appreciated, thank you!

````
 let EmbedError = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
 .setColor('#FFFFFF')
 .setDescription(`You already own ${message.guild.roles.cache.get('733373020491481219')} !`);
        return message.channel.send(EmbedError)

 }else if (author < 20000) return message.channel.send(Embed)
     db.subtract(`money_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`, 20000)

     db.fetch(`hot_rod_red${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`);
     db.set(`hot_rod_red_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`, true)
 
    let Embed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setColor("#FFFFFF")
     .setDescription(`:white_check_mark: You bought ${message.guild.roles.cache.get('733373020491481219')} for 20,000 credits!`);
     message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add("733373020491481219")
     db.subtract(`money_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`, 20000)
     db.push(message.author.id, `${message.guild.roles.cache.get('733373020491481219')}`);
     message.channel.send(Embed2)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```js
if (message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Role Name")) {
//extract less points
} else {
//extract normal amount of points
}
```

Comment: Looks like that got the job done, need to organize my code a little, getting mixed up message replies, but it works, thank you!!